# Sisense, display number of days in date filter

Tags: date, filter, formula, sisense

Have a date filter on the dashboard that allows for a custom date range:

[Dashboard Date Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGIyz.png)

How can I add a the number of days in the filter to a formula?  Just trying to show the number of days in column of a pivot table.  In this example the date range is 45 days.  The dataset doesn't have one record for each day, so a distinct count of days from the data set returns 42.

Is it possible to use the date from and date to filter values in formula?   DDIFF([datefilter-from], [datefilter-to])

Answer (score 1):

Extract the date from the fact table and create a dimension table which will contain all the dates.
Link the date column from fact table and dimension table. Use the dimension table's date column in filters.